# Built in way of doing successive Ruby evals on the same object

Tags: ruby

**Edit:** I just realized my prior example was bad.

Borrowing @ZachKemp's idea (and changing it):

```
class Object
  def eval_multi(*methods)
    #methods.inject(self) { |memo, m| memo.send(m) }
    methods.inject(self) { |memo, m| eval("#{memo}.#{m}") }
  end
end

[1,2,3].eval_multi("product([4,5,6])", :transpose)
=> [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]]
```

I'm wondering if there's a built-in way of doing this without having to write the `eval_multi` method above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `inject`:

```
module Enumerable
  def multimap(*methods)
    methods.inject(self){|result, method| result.map(&method) }
  end
end

arr = ["1 a", "1 b", "2 c", "2 a"]

arr.multimap(:split, :reverse, :join)
#=> ["a1", "b1", "c2", "a2"]
```

(I renamed the method because `eval` already has another meaning in Ruby).

Comment: Is there a built-in way of doing this? I was just giving an example above :-)

Comment: No there's no built-in way of doing it, but this only uses core methods, so it's close.

Comment: This is simple enough, I'll accept it. There's something little still itching but I think it's another question.. I'll ask in a new post :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use one map, simple and clean.

```
arr.map{ |o| o.split.reverse.join }
```

Comment: I believe those those three methods are just examples, that the question concerns methods held in variables.

Comment: Thanks :-) I probably gave a bad example by using `map` on an `Array`.  I edited my question giving a clearer example =)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a little change in the way you pass the arguments.

```
[[:product, [4,5,6]], [:transpose]].inject([1,2,3]){|m, a| m.send(*a)}
# => [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Or, by modifying `send` a little bit, you can do it like this:

```
class Object
  def send_splat a; send(*a) end
end

[[:product, [4,5,6]], [:transpose]].inject([1,2,3], &:send_splat)
# => [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]]
```